# cmake add_library STATIC - работает, OBJECT - undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake

Я не профессионал в использовании cmake. Есть личный проект и я пытаюсь разработать его с cmake и вот тут незадача, просто не могу понять как это преодолеть.

Пример сруктуры проекта:

```
root
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-src/
  |-CMakeLists.txt
  |-main.cpp
  |-data/
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |-data_units
      |-CMakeLists.txt
      |-data_unit1.cpp
```

Содержимое:

root/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(src)
```

root/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(data)
add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE data)
```

root/src/data/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(data_units)
add_library(data INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(data INTERFACE data_units)
```

root/src/data/data_units/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(data_unit1 OBJECT data_unit1.cpp)
add_library(data_units INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(data_uints INTERFACE data_unit1)
```

В main.cpp идет создание класса из data_unit1.cpp, если в add_library для data_unit1 указывается OBJECT, то линковщик выдает undefined reference to 'этот класс'. Если же сделать STATIC в add_library для data_unit1, то всё хорошо.

Я не могу найти решение и понять что я делаю не так. Мне бы хотелось избавиться от необходимости создавать лишний раз библиотеку.

Версия cmake 3.27.7

**UPD:**

Если написать $<TARGET_OBJECTS:data>, то ошибка, что TARGET_OBJECTS не работает для INTERFACE.

Comment: Оставьте один cmake файл с `add_executable(exe "src/main.cpp" "src/data/data_units/data_unit1.cpp")`

Comment: Зачем нужно две интерфейсные либы? Линкайте приложение сразу к объектной либе.

Comment: @arrowd, можно подробнее?:)

Comment: @arrowd, дело в том, что помимо data_units интерфейс data будет включать и другие директории. Их может быть много, и я хочу через data передать всё для исполняемого файла. Якобы для будущей разработки, человеку нужно включить свои объектные файлы в data без необходимости "ковырять" вышестоящий CMakeLists

Comment: Передать можно и просто списком файлов, зачем создавать интерфейсные либы и передавать список либ?

Comment: @arrowd, мне не нужно либы передавать, я хочу объекты передать. делать OBJECT набор в одном CMakeLists, а включить этот набор в вышестоящем одним словом, мне кажется так более структурировано и грамотно. Я, возможно не до конца понимаю что такое INTERFACE, но я думал теперь вы поняли меня и можете сказать как сделать лучше, или может вы знаете как мне передать OBJECT в первую директорию из третьей вложеной, а если это не реализуемо, то как тогда мне список файлов передать ?:)